# Integral of ArcCos with Difficult Argument

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I have

$$\int_{d-1}^{1}2 x \arccos\left(\frac{x^2+d^2-1}{2 x d}\right)\,\textrm{d} x$$

but can't find the right substitution. I have little experience integrating $\arccos$ with anything but trivial arguments and would be very grateful if an expert out there could give me a quick lesson, if this is even tractable.

Comment: assume the argument of the $\arccos$ ensures a real value of the trig function; also $1<d<2$.

Comment: Have you tried integration by part? 2x can be integrated and the arccos part can be derived. The result is ugly but you can get rid of the trig stuff.

Comment: Thought there might be a more elegant way, but I can try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is easier to integrate by parts first instead of looking for some clever substitution. One reason I advocate this approach is that it makes it apparent that elliptic integrals are avoidable faster, and because the subsequent substitutions are straightforward (though perhaps algebraically tedious).

Assume $1<d<2$.

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(d\right)}
&=\int_{d-1}^{1}2x\,\arccos{\left(\frac{x^2+d^2-1}{2xd}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\left[x^2\arccos{\left(\frac{x^2+d^2-1}{2xd}\right)}\right]_{d-1}^{1}-\int_{d-1}^{1}x^2\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\arccos{\left(\frac{x^2+d^2-1}{2xd}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\left[\arccos{\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)}-(d-1)^2\arccos{\left(1\right)}\right]+\frac{1}{2d}\int_{d-1}^{1}\frac{x^2-d^2+1}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{x^2+d^2-1}{2xd}\right)^2}}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\arccos{\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)}+\frac{1}{2d}\int_{d-1}^{1}\frac{x^2-d^2+1}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{x^2+d^2-1}{2xd}\right)^2}}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\arccos{\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)}+\frac{1}{2d}\int_{d-1}^{1}\frac{2dx\left(x^2-d^2+1\right)}{\sqrt{4d^2x^2-\left(x^2+d^2-1\right)^2}}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\arccos{\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)}+\frac12\int_{d-1}^{1}\frac{x^2-d^2+1}{\sqrt{4d^2x^2-\left(x^2+d^2-1\right)^2}}\,2x\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\arccos{\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)}+\frac12\int_{(d-1)^2}^{1}\frac{y-d^2+1}{\sqrt{4d^2y-\left(y+d^2-1\right)^2}}\,\mathrm{d}y;~~[x^2=y]\\
&=\arccos{\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)}+\frac12\int_{(d-1)^2}^{1}\frac{y-d^2+1}{\sqrt{4d^2-\left(y-d^2-1\right)^2}}\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\arccos{\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)}+\frac12\int_{-2d}^{-d^2}\frac{z+2}{\sqrt{4d^2-z^2}}\,\mathrm{d}z;~~[y-d^2-1=z]\\
&=\arccos{\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)}+\frac12\int_{-1}^{-\frac{d}{2}}\frac{2dt+2}{\sqrt{4d^2-4d^2t^2}}\,2d\,\mathrm{d}t;~~[\frac{z}{2d}=t]\\
&=\arccos{\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)}+\int_{-1}^{-\frac{d}{2}}\frac{d\,t+1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\arccos{\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)}+\int_{-1}^{-\frac{d}{2}}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}+\frac{d}{2}\int_{-1}^{-\frac{d}{2}}\frac{2t\,\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\\
&=\arccos{\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)}+\int_{\frac{d}{2}}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}+\frac{d}{2}\int_{1}^{\frac{d^2}{4}}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\sqrt{1-u}};~~[t^2=u]\\
&=\arccos{\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)}+\arccos{\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)}+\frac{d}{2}\sqrt{4-d^2}\\
&=2\arccos{\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)}+\frac{d}{2}\sqrt{4-d^2}.~\blacksquare\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks David! This is a massive help.

Comment: @AlexanderGiles You're quite welcome. Also, I've noticed that you've asked a few other questions that seem to be related to this one. Do you think my response here is sufficient to figure the others out on your own? Because if not, I'd be happy to respond to those too. :)

Comment: Yes, as along as the other integrals in my previous questions don't break under this sort of integration by parts I should be fine, but feel free to have a go, particularly http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1111290/integral-involving-a-radical-by-arccos-leftfx-right-any-help